# Sonarqube 6.2 Scan on a Java File

Tags: sonarqube

Running a scan but the scan took more than 1 hour?
How can I debug this?

The log indicates  (current same file for more than 1 hour)

02:07:31.712 [INFO] 15/75 files analyzed, current file:

02:07:41.712 [INFO] 15/75 files analyzed, current file:

lines of code in that file is 2000 lines. ( java )

**Snippet of Trace/Log**

```
00:04:13.734 [DEBUG] 11:21:31.858 /a/.m2/repository/com/***/***/bigsql-sync/5.79.0.955/bigsql-sync-5.79.0.955.jar
00:04:13.734 [DEBUG] 11:21:31.858 -----
00:04:13.939 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.079 Could not complete symbolic execution: 
00:04:13.939 org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker$MaximumStepsReachedException: reached limit of 16000 steps for method exec#63 in class HCAT_DESCRIBETAB
00:04:13.939    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.throwMaxSteps(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:276)
00:04:13.939    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.execute(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:227)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:200)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:193)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.execute(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:77)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.visitNode(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:62)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:95)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:78)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:64)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:108)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:86)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:63)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:119)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:113)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:84)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:182)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:242)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:240)
00:04:13.940    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:232)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
00:04:13.941    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:04:13.941    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:04:13.941    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:04:13.941    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
00:04:13.941    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.execute(Unknown Source)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
00:04:13.941    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:122)
00:04:13.941    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
00:04:13.941    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
00:04:13.941    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
00:04:13.941    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
00:04:13.941    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
00:04:13.941    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
00:04:13.941    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
00:04:13.941    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
00:04:13.942    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
00:04:13.942    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
00:04:13.942    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
00:04:13.942    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:04:13.942    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:04:13.942    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:04:13.942    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:04:13.942    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
00:04:13.942    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
00:04:13.942    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:181)
00:04:13.942    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:04:13.942    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:04:13.942    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:04:13.942    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:04:13.942    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
00:04:13.942    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
00:04:13.942    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
00:04:13.942    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
00:04:13.942    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
00:04:13.942    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
00:04:13.942    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
00:04:13.942    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
00:04:13.942    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
00:04:13.942    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
00:04:13.942 
00:04:14.104 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 ----- Classpath analyzed by Squid:
00:04:14.104 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/target/classes
00:04:14.104 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/2.7.3-***-11/hadoop-client-2.7.3-***-11.jar
00:04:14.104 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.3-***-11/hadoop-common-2.7.3-***-11.jar
00:04:14.104 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.1.1/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar
00:04:14.104 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
00:04:14.104 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.1/commons-net-3.1.jar
00:04:14.104 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
00:04:14.105 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar
00:04:14.105 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
00:04:14.105 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar
00:04:14.105 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.7.3-***-11/hadoop-auth-2.7.3-***-11.jar
00:04:14.105 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-kerberos-codec/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar
00:04:14.105 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-i18n/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar
00:04:14.105 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-asn1-api/1.0.0-M20/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar
00:04:14.105 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-util/1.0.0-M20/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar
00:04:14.105 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.243 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-client/2.7.1/curator-client-2.7.1.jar
```

**Another Block**

```
00:04:14.122 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.245 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-tests/2.6.0-***-7/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0-***-7-tests.jar
00:04:14.123 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.245 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/2.6.0-***-7/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0-***-7.jar
00:04:14.123 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.245 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/2.6.0-***-7/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-***-7-tests.jar
00:04:14.123 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.245 /a/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-servlet/3.0/guice-servlet-3.0.jar
00:04:14.123 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.245 /a/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/2.6.0-***-7/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0-***-7.jar
00:04:14.123 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.245 /a/.m2/repository/com/***/***/bigsql-sync/5.79.0.955/bigsql-sync-5.79.0.955.jar
00:04:14.123 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.245 -----
00:04:14.424 [DEBUG] 11:21:32.564 Could not complete symbolic execution: 
00:04:14.425 org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker$MaximumStepsReachedException: reached limit of 16000 steps for method getSyncList#1467 in class HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.throwMaxSteps(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:276)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.execute(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:227)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:200)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.execute(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:73)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.xproc.BehaviorCache.get(BehaviorCache.java:68)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.executeMethodInvocation(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:630)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visit(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:502)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.execute(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:238)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:200)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.execute(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:73)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.visitNode(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:62)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:95)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:78)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:64)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:108)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:86)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:63)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:119)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:113)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:84)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:182)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
00:04:14.425    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:242)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:240)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:232)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
00:04:14.426    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:04:14.426    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:04:14.426    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:04:14.426    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
00:04:14.426    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.execute(Unknown Source)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
00:04:14.426    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:122)
00:04:14.426    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
00:04:14.426    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
00:04:14.426    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
00:04:14.426    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
00:04:14.426    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
00:04:14.426    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
00:04:14.426    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
00:04:14.426    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
00:04:14.426    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
00:04:14.426    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
00:04:14.426    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
00:04:14.426    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:04:14.426    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:04:14.426    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:04:14.426    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:04:14.426    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
00:04:14.426    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
00:04:14.426    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:181)
00:04:14.426    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:04:14.426    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:04:14.426    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:04:14.427    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:04:14.427    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
00:04:14.427    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
00:04:14.427    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
00:04:14.427    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
00:04:14.427    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
00:04:14.427    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
00:04:14.427    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
00:04:14.427    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
00:04:14.427    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
00:04:14.427    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
00:04:14.427 
00:04:21.870 [INFO] 11:21:40.008 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:04:31.870 [INFO] 11:21:50.008 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:04:41.870 [INFO] 11:22:00.009 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:04:51.869 [INFO] 11:22:10.009 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:05:01.869 [INFO] 11:22:20.009 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:05:11.870 [INFO] 11:22:30.009 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:05:21.870 [INFO] 11:22:40.009 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:05:31.870 [INFO] 11:22:50.010 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:05:41.870 [INFO] 11:23:00.010 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:05:51.871 [INFO] 11:23:10.010 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:06:01.870 [INFO] 11:23:20.010 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
00:06:11.871 [INFO] 11:23:30.010 15/75 files analyzed, current file: /a/va/workspace/Sonar_***_x86-RH6_Master/***/bigsql-udf/src/main/java/com/***/***/biga/udf/HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS.java
```

Comment: Is this a Java project?

Comment: Can you please rerun an analysis in debug mode and paste the logs? Debug mode is activated with "-X" if you're using Maven, or "-Dsonar.verbose=true" more generally. Also, if the code of this file is not confidential, providing it would help a lot.